# Difference in document load time Firebase Realtime vs Firebase Firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm wondering, even with very simple code, why Firestore is significantly slower than Realtime Database with Firebase.

---

### **Cloud Firestore:**

**Cold start**: Function execution took **1562 ms**

**Hot start:** Function execution took **132 ms**

```
exports.firestore = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    var teamRef = instance.collection('teams').doc("TGQ");
    teamRef.get().then(doc => {
        res.status(200).send(doc.data()).end();
        return;
    }).catch(error => {
        res.status(200).send("Document cant be found").end();
    });
});
```

---

### Realtime Database

**Cold start**: Function execution took **815 ms**

**Hot start:** Function execution took **13 ms**

```
exports.realtimedb = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    var realtime = admin.database();
    realtime.ref('/teams/' + "TGQ").once('value').then((snapshot) => {
        var document = snapshot.val();
        res.status(200).send(document).end();
        return;
    }).catch(error => {
        res.status(200).send("Document cant be found").end();
    });
});
```

---

Why with simple functions does Cloud Firestore act so slowly? I personally think, for the project I'm running, that Firestore is the one for me but it seems very off putting that it's twice as slow on a cold start and 10 times slower on a hot start.

Both servers are hosted at US Central 1 too. I've looked into the complexity of the js file they're run from and these two examples are run from the same file to give an even result.

Comment: The code for the Firestore example exports `realtimedb` and vice versa for Realtime. Is that a typo, or does that mean your results are flipped?

Comment: updated, it was a copy and paste error - thanks for the spot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference in cold start loading time is typically purely a function of the SDK size. The SDK for Cloud Firestore (plus its dependencies) is significantly larger than the one for the Realtime Database, and this additional code has to be loaded into each new instance.

The difference in document load time is harder to break down. It's typically a mix of the distance between where you run your Cloud Functions and where the database is, combined with the number of hops it takes to establish the connection, the bandwidth of the data read, and the overhead of the protocol used.

The infrastructure, architecture, and protocol between the two databases are very different, so comparing them is hard beyond a simple: "look at that, X is faster" as you've seen here.